# Quisiera saber cual es la diferencia entre una variable y una constante en el lenguaje de Python

Tags: python

Me podrian ayudar  tengo una duda que diferencia hay entre variable y constante  en el lenguaje de python

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Tu pregunta no demuestra que hayas intentado averiguar nada por ti mismo. Que leíste o buscaste al respecto?

Comment: Aportar además que para python son todo objetos, no hay diferencia entre variable y constante ya que las generas igual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Una constante** en Python será siempre aquella variable declarada que no cambiará su valor durante el tiempo de ejecución. 
(Se declara en mayúsculas) [Consultar PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants)

> Nota: Este tema de constantes en Python será meramente de estilos de escritura. Como tal no existe este comportamiento natural en el lenguaje como lo pudiéramos realizar en otros lenguajes.

**Una variable** será utilizada como soporte de tus operaciones y mutará o cambiará de valor según los flujos que manejes en tu lógica programada. (Se declara en minúsculas.)

Ahora te doy algunos ejemplos:

**CONSTANTES**

Puedes crear un archivo en python llamado settings.py y agregar variables como estas:

```
CONFIG_URL_RESPONSE = "https://XXXXXX.XXX"
LOGIN_ATTEMPS = 2
MAX_UPLOAD = 100M
```

Y luego podrás hacer uso de los mismos de la siguiente forma:

```
from . import settings

print(settings.CONFIG_URL_RESPONSE)
print(settings.LOGIN_ATTEMPS)
print(settings.MAX_UPLOAD)
```

**VARIABLES**

La variable se utilizará así:

```
result = 0
num_1 = 2
num_2 = 3
result = num_1 + num_2
print(result)
```

Como puedes apreciar, la variable *result* cambió de valor en tiempo de ejecución y podrá cambiar sin problema tantas veces sea necesario.

> Nota: 
>   Es importante mencionar que Python es un lenguaje flexible en el tema de declaración de variables. Si en tiempo de ejecución se modifica una variable que se asume como constante, el lenguaje lo cambiará sin presentar error alguno. 
>   Para evitar realizar cambios en estas constantes, podemos hacer un pequeño truco declarando una clase con métodos dentro de la misma y decorarlas como constantes. Esto se hace de la siguiente manera:

```
def is_constant(f):
    def fset(self, value):
        raise TypeError
    def fget(self):
        return f()
    return property(fget, fset)


class SettingsClass:

    @is_constant
    def MAX_UPLOAD():
        return 20
```

Para utilizarlo realizarías lo siguiente:

```
from settings import SettingsClass

sett = SettingsClass()
print(sett.MAX_UPLOAD)
sett.MAX_UPLOAD = 100   # <-- Aquí se generaría un error
print(sett.MAX_UPLOAD)
```

Comment: eso quiere decir que tendras un error en tiempo de ejecucion si tratas de modificar una constante? si no, es solo una declaracion semantica

Comment: Python es flexible en su declaración de variables. Si cambias una de estas constantes no ocasionarás error en la ejecución pero perderá el sentido de utilizar estas variables como constantes. Si deseas evitar que pase esto entonces recomendaría crear una clase con funciones con decorador @constant para evitarlo. Ver https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/how-to-create-a-constant-in-python

Comment: Entonces estaría bien aclarar que las constantes en este lenguaje son solo decorativas, ya que no tienen un uso como constante real. Y la declaración en mayúscula o minúscula también es semántica? no parece ejercer ninguna diferencia en el lenguaje.

Comment: Editado, gracias por la recomendación :)

Answer (score 0):

En Python no existe el concepto de constante tal como uno podría imaginárselo desde la óptica de otro lenguaje como **C**. Veamos por que:

En primer lugar ¿Que es una variable? En Python una variable es una referencia a un objeto de alguna clase, un entero, una cadena, una lista, una diccionario, etc. Lo importante es que la variable es una referencia y no es el objeto. Por esto, una referencia siempre puede ser "reasignable", por ejemplo, puedo declarar `HTTP_PORT = 80` y asumir que `HTTP_PORT` es una constante, pero no deja de ser una convención, `HTTP_PORT` es una referencia a un entero cuyo valor es `80`, pero en cualquier lugar/momento puedo reasignar la variable/referencia haciendo algo así `HTTP_PORT = 8080` y ahora `HTTP_PORT` "apunta" a otro objeto entero cuyo valor es `8080`

Resumiendo, no existen las constantes de usuario en Python, si, podemos usar como convención que las variables en mayúsculas no se reasignan y las usamos como  valores constantes, somos todos adultos y sabemos que no tenemos que tocarlas. Notese que antes mencioné las "constantes de usuario", por que Python si tiene ciertas constantes propias como ser `True`, `False`, `None` etc. [Más info](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/constants.html).

Existen alternativas a las constantes, por ejemplo, se puede implementar una clase que permita configurar sus propiedades durante la inicialización y que no permita la modificación de estas luego. Por ejemplo [aquí](http://www.pygopar.com/mimicking-constants-in-python/) una implementación bien sencilla.

```
class PyConstObj(object):  
    """ Implementation of a constant object in Python """
    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for name, value in kwargs.items():
            super(PyConstObj, self).__setattr__(name, value)

    # --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __setattr__(self, name, val):
        """ When trying to set a new value to the constant object """
        # If variable already exists in instance
        if name in self.__dict__:
            raise ValueError("Cannot change value of a constant")
        else:
            super(PyConstObj, self).__setattr__(name, val)

config = PyConstObj(HTTP_PORT=80, GOOGLE_URL="http://www.google.com")

print(config.HTTP_PORT)
print(config.GOOGLE_URL)

config.HTTP_PORT = 80

> 80
> http://www.google.com
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "python", line 22, in <module>
>   File "python", line 13, in __setattr__
> ValueError: Cannot change value of a constant
```

O incluso, mucho más fácil con la clase [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

```
import collections

constantes = collections.namedtuple('config', 'HTTP_PORT GOOGLE_URL')
config = constantes(HTTP_PORT=80, GOOGLE_URL="http://www.google.com")

print(config.HTTP_PORT)
print(config.GOOGLE_URL)

config.HTTP_PORT = 80

> 80
> http://www.google.com
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "python", line 10, in <module>
> AttributeError: can't set attribute
```